# Python Memorybuffer pywin32

Tags: python, buffer, pywin32

I got some code:

```
    def get_text(self, id):
        edit_hwnd = win32gui.GetDlgItem(self.hwnd, id)  # 获取窗口句柄
        time.sleep(0.2)
        self.edit_hwnd = edit_hwnd
        length = win32api.SendMessage(
             edit_hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH) + 1  # 获取窗体内容长度
        buf = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(length)  # 准备buffer对象作为容器
        win32gui.SendMessage(edit_hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXT,
                         length, buf)  # 获取窗体内容放入容器
        try:
            address, length = win32gui.PyGetBufferAddressAndLen(buf)  # 获取容器的内存地址
        except ValueError:
            print('error')
            return
        text = win32gui.PyGetString(address, length)  # 取得字符串
        buf.release()
        del buf
        return text
```

This function for get string at windows.I need to while this func to always get this value.When the value changed,i do something.But now when i done this while,my program exit with error code C000005.How can i fix it.

```
buf.release()
del buf
```

It's i added when i found this problem.It look like does't work.

Comment: Just guessing: `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` returns the number of _characters_ while `PyMakeBuffer` creates a buffer with given number of _bytes_ but a character may consist of multiple bytes (usually two but I'm not sure if this is always enough)

Comment: Please how can i test it.what will happen if the buffer does't enough.

Comment: It work for me ,thank you.I change length+1 to length * 2.Then i never see the damned error code.Can you add a answer? I will accept it.

Comment: The buffer size should be better `length * 2 + 2`, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages [`WM_GETTEXTLENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-gettextlength) returns the length of the text in *characters* (*excluding* the terminating null character) and the maximum buffer length given to [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-gettext) also is based on characters (*including* the terminating null character).

A character in the NT-based Windows systems is encoded in a double-byte character set (DBCS), meaning two bytes per character.

The function `win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(length)` returns a buffer of `length` *bytes*.

So if `length` is the return value of `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH`, the reserved buffer should be `length * 2 + 2` bytes long and the maximum buffer length given to `WM_GETTEXT` should be `length + 1`.